# Can UI show input parameters which is not PipelineParam in kubeflow-pipelines?

Tags: kubeflow, kubeflow-pipelines

In kubeflow-pipelines, UI shows PipelineParam as input parameters.

However, I want to confirm values which are not PipelineParam but constant value. 
Is there any way to show the values in UI?

For example, only param_a is shown in UI in the following case.

```
def pipeline(param_a=3):
    ...
    component = op1(param_a, param_b=3)
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a limitation of the current KFP's DSL compiler. We're working on making the constant value arguments visible. Unfortunately, currently they're inlined in the command-line. In the latest UX the command-line can be inspected by looking at the Pod tab.